# How to have a custom start layout only for new users?

Tags: windows-10, powershell, group-policy, start-menu

I want to to have a customized start layout for my company's Windows 10 machines before we migrate. I've found the Import-Layout powershell cmdlet, but as far as I'm aware that only applies to the current user.

I also found a Group Policy setting called Start Layout. But the description says that it also locks down the start menu, not allowing for users to change it.

This basic customized one is just to have all the essentials every employee needs, quite a few have other programs that are not standard, and they'll likely want start menu shortcuts.

I want a customized start menu that only applies to new users, not existing users, and that allows users to still further customize their start menu. What's the best way to do this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Import-Layout actually only applies to the default user profile- applying to all new users only, without restricting them. Turns out I was wrong thinking it applies only to the user running the script.